# Codeigniter - How to display Price or Discount Price in Market

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I tried million times display Discount Price if in table serviceDPrice is not null. When Discount Price is not null, I want to display Discount Price. If Discount Price is null, I want to display normal Price that name is servicePrice in table. I tried some codes for this but not work clearly. I set up serviceDPrice and servicePrice to decimals. How I can edit this code to working ?

Code:

```
<?php

    if ($get->serviceDPrice == null) {
        echo '€' . '<del>' . $get->servicePrice . '</del>';
    } elseif ($get->serviceDPrice != null) {
        echo '';
    }

?>
```

Comment: I formatted your code for better readability.

Comment: Thanks for ur editing Philipp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like ..

```
<?php echo (( isset($get->serviceDPrice) && $get->serviceDPrice != '' ) ? '€'.  '<del>'  .$get->servicePrice. '</del>' : ''); ?>
```

Comment: are you sure that you're getting this variable null or something else ?

Comment: Yas I am sure. If you want I put my table here with structure.

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary also

```
<?= ($get->serviceDPrice != null) ? '€'.  '<del>'  .$get->servicePrice. '</del>' : '' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please debug your code 
`var_dump($get->serviceDPrice);`

should do the trick
if the var_dump, dumps NULL than you should make the if else like this

```
if($get->serviceDPrice === NULL)
{
   // does not have discount
}
else
{
   // the price has discount
}
```

if var_dump dumps FALSE, than instead of NULL put FALSE

Comment: var_dump($get->serviceDPrice); takes NULL but in code this is not working.

Comment: what do you mean takes NULL... it prints NULL when var_dump($get->serviceDPrice);

if its NULL that means there is no discount